# Camel CXF producer basic auth

Tags: authentication, cxf, apache-camel

I'm new to Apache Camel and CXF, and I'm trying to create a route for querying a remote WS which requires Basic Authentication and to specify the SoapAction header. I achieved it with the spring-ws component but I was wondering if I could do the same with the cxf component.

My current configuration is:

> RouteBuilder

```
from("file:src/test/resources/data?noop=true")
    .to("xquery:transform/search.xquery")
    .to("cxf:-----")
    .to("log:TestApp");
```

I've read something about conduits but I don't know how to configure it in my current camel context.

> CamelContext

```
<camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <package>my.package</package>
</camel:camelContext>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the Camel HTTP component:

http://server.com?authMethod=Basic&authUsername=user&authPassword=password

However, you probably want to take advantage of the functionality that CXF offers.

You can set up a CXF bean in camel and then set up a HTTP conduit to provide the Basic Auth:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport%28includingSSLsupport%29-BasicAuthentication

```
<conduit name="https://localhost:.*""
   xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
   xmlns="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration">
   <authorization>
      <sec:UserName>myuser</sec:UserName>
      <sec:Password>mypasswd</sec:Password>
      <sec:AuthorizationType>Basic</sec:AuthorizationType>
   </authorization>
 </conduit>
```

The HTTP Conduit links to the Camel CXF bean using the 'name' parameter.  You set it to a URL like I did above or check the documentation for setting it to a URI matching your service.

Thanks,
Yogesh

Comment: Thanks Yogesh I'll try it out ASAP